# docker mysql container not running suddenly

Tags: docker, mysql

docker mysql container was working perfectl.But after restarting of the server and using the start command to run the conatiner it is not working.My other containers are all up and running as normal.But mysql shows status exited.If I do docker start conatiner id it takes the command.But I am unable to enter into the container .Please find the attachment also[image: docker mysql container status]

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the specific error it looks like the container's runtime process is either crashing or exiting.  When a docker container's runtime process exits the container stops. 
 You can get more information about the specific error by using the [docker logs command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/):

```
docker logs 92455a993a54
```